# Dry/wet (i.e. include partial raw signal) parameter on IIR notch filter before convolution with other filters

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have a group of scipy.signal.iirnotch filters convolving with one another and I would like each to implement independent dry/wet values for each of them. I know I can achieve a pseudo-dry/wet parameter by adding them to one another instead of performing a convolution on them but that is janky and difficult to control.

I am just at the start of my DSP learning but I haven't been able find any documentation/information on something like this so I have no idea where else to start other than poking around at the coefficients (to no avail). Here is the isolated relevant code so far:

```
from scipy import signal
notch_freqs = (220, 440, 880) # could be any frequencies, these are just placeholders
notch_coeffs = [signal.iirnotch(freq, BANDWIDTH, samplerate) for freq in notch_freqs]

# here would be the step in applying the dry/wet to each coefficient in notch_coeffs

# and then the convolution would happen...
def convolve_notches():  # I know this can probably be optimized but it works for now
    filter_conv_a = signal.fftconvolve(*[filt[0] for filt in notch_coeffs[:2]])
    filter_conv_b = signal.fftconvolve(*[filt[1] for filt in notch_coeffs[:2]])

    if len(notch_coeffs) > 2:
         for filt in notch_coeffs[:2]:
            filter_conv_a = signal.fftconvolve(filter_conv_a, filt[0])
            filter_conv_b = signal.fftconvolve(filter_conv_b, filt[1])
    return filter_conv_a, filter_conv_b

# ... then apply using signal.filtfilt
```

This is not a real-time audio application so I'm not too concerned about timing.
Rereading this, I want to clarify dry/wet; here's an ASCII representation:

```
Wet: 25%       50%         100%
---\    /----\     /----\       /----
    \__/      \   /      \     /
               \_/        \   /
                           | |
                           | |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do this.  First, a couple observations:

- To incorporate the "wet" factor, we can use a little algrebra.
  An IIR filter can be represented as the rational function

  ```
          P_B(z)
  H(z) =  ------
          P_A(z)
  ```

  where P_A(z) and P_B(z) are polynomials in z⁻¹.  A notch filter
  will have a gain of 0 at the center frequency, but you want to
  mix the "wet" and "dry" (i.e. filtered and unfiltered) signals.
  Let w be the "wet" fraction, 0 <= w <= 1, so w = 0 implies no
  filtering, w=0.25 implies the gain is 0.75 at the notch frequency,
  etc.  Such a filter can be expressed as

  ```
                          P_B(z)   (1 - w)*P_A(z) + w*P_B(z)
  H(z) =  (1 - w) + (w) * ------ = -------------------------
                          P_A(z)            P_A(z)
  ```

  In terms of the arrays of coefficients returned in a call such
  as `b, a = iirnotch(w0, Q, fs)`, the coefficients of the modified
  filter are `b_mod = (1-w)*a + w*b` and `a_mod = a`.
- `iirnotch(w0, Q, fs)` returns two 1-d arrays of length 3.  These
  are the coefficients of the "biquad" notch filter.  To create
  a new filter that is a cascade of several notch filters, you
  can simply stack the arrays returned by `iirnotch` into an
  array with shape (n, 6); this is the *SOS* (second order sections)
  format for a filter.  This format is actually the recommended
  format for filters beyond a few orders, because it is numerically
  more robust than the (b, a) format (which requires high order
  polynomials).

Here's a script that demonstrate how these points can be used
to implement your desired cascade of notch filters with varying
"wetness" for each notch:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import iirnotch, sosfreqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


samplerate = 4000
notch_freqs = (220, 440, 880)
Q = 12.5

filters = [iirnotch(freq, Q, samplerate) for freq in notch_freqs]

# Stack the filter coefficients into an array with shape
# (len(notch_freqs, 6)).  This array of "second order sections"
# can be used with sosfilt, sosfreqz, etc.

# This version, `sos`, is the combined filter without taking
# into account the desired "wet" factor.  This is created just
# for comparison to the filter with "wet" factors.
sos = np.block([[b, a] for b, a in filters])

# sos2 includes the desired "wet" factor of the notch filters.
wet = (0.25, 0.5, 1.0)
sos2 = np.block([[(1-w)*a + w*b, a] for w, (b, a) in zip(wet, filters)])

# Compute the frequency responses of the two filters.
w, h = sosfreqz(sos, worN=8000, fs=samplerate)
w2, h2 = sosfreqz(sos2, worN=8000, fs=samplerate)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(w, np.abs(h), '--', alpha=0.75, label='Simple cascade')
plt.plot(w2, np.abs(h2), alpha=0.8, label='With "wet" factor')
plt.title('Frequency response of cascaded notch filters')
for yw in wet:
    plt.axhline(1 - yw, color='k', alpha=0.4, linestyle=':')
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.ylabel('|H(f)|')
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True, loc=(0.6, 0.25))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(w, np.angle(h), '--', alpha=0.75, label='Simple cascade')
plt.plot(w2, np.angle(h2), alpha=0.8, label='With "wet" factor')
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.ylabel('∠H(f) (radians)')
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True, loc=(0.6, 0.25))
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot that is generated by the script:

[image]